# How to put command of build docker container to dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have script: `docker run -it -p 4000:4000 bitgosdk/express:latest --disablessl -e test`
how to put this command to dockerfile with arguments?

```
FROM bitgosdk/express:latest
EXPOSE 4000
???
```

Comment: so the command is just `--disablessl -e test` ? What is the output of `ps -ef` inside your running container?

Answer (score 2):

Gone through your [Dockerfile contents](https://github.com/BitGo/BitGoJS/blob/master/Dockerfile).

The command running inside container is:

```
/ # ps -ef | more
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:00 /sbin/tini -- /usr/local/bin/node /var/bitgo-express/bin/bitgo-express --disablessl -e test
```

The command is so because the entrypoint set in the Dockerfile is `ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/tini", "--", "/usr/local/bin/node", "/var/bitgo-express/bin/bitgo-express"]` and the arguments `--disablessl -e test` are the one provided while running `docker run` command.

The `--disablessl -e test` arguments can be set inside your Dockerfile using `CMD`:

```
CMD ["--disablessl", "-e","test"]
```

**New Dockerfile**:

```
FROM bitgosdk/express:latest
EXPOSE 4000
CMD ["--disablessl", "-e","test"]
```

Refer this to know the [difference between entrypoint and cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile).

Answer (score 1):

You don't.
This is what docker-compose is used for.

i.e. create a `docker-compose.yml` with contents like this:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  test:
    image: bitgodsdk/express:latest
    command: --disablessl -e test
    ports:
    - "4000:4000"
```

and then execute the following in a terminal to access the interactive terminal for the service named test.

`docker-compose run test`

Comment: I generally consider Compose `command:` an override, and I'd consider setting a default Dockerfile `CMD` preferable.

Comment: True. But if that is the only thing requring a Dockerfile, then better to keep it as a compose-file override and skip the hassle of working with a custom image.

Answer (score 0):

Even if [@mchawre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65558433/9164010) seems to directly answer OP's question "syntactically speaking" (as a Dockerfile was asked), a `docker-compose.yml` is definitely the way to go to make a `docker run` command, as *custom* as it might be, reproducible in a *declarative* way ([YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML%20Ain%27t%20Markup%20Language) file).

Just to complement [@ChrisBecke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65558432/9164010), note that the writing of this YAML file can be automated. See e.g., the FOSS (under MIT license) https://github.com/magicmark/composerize

FTR, the snippet below was automatically generated from the following `docker run` command, using the accompanying webapp https://composerize.com/:

> `docker run -it -p 4000:4000 bitgosdk/express:latest`

```yaml
version: '3.3'
services:
    express:
        ports:
            - '4000:4000'
        image: 'bitgosdk/express:latest'
```

I omitted the `CMD` arguments `--disablessl -e test` on-purpose, as `composerize` does not seem to support these extra arguments. This may sound like a bug (and FTR [a related issue is opened](https://github.com/magicmark/composerize/issues/219)), but meanwhile it might just be viewed as a feature, in line of [@DavidMaze's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65558209/how-to-put-command-of-build-docker-container-to-dockerfile#comment115914697_65558432)…