# Dockerize vue project

Tags: docker, vue.js, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have installed a simple vue project via cli.
I've created Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml file.

But after ***docker-compose build && docker-compose up*** I get 404 page

**Project Structure**

- simple-chat

  - docker

    - docker-compose.yml
    - Dockerfile
  - public
  - src
  - package.json

the commands

```
cd docker 
docker build -t simple-chat .. 
winpty docker run -it -p 8080:8080 --rm --name simple-chat simple-chat
```

opens http://localhost:8080 correctly

The commands

```
docker-compose build --no-cache 
docker-compose up
```

returns 404 page in browser

What I did wrong  ?

***Dockerfile***

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
RUN npm install -g http-server

WORKDIR /app/simple-chat

COPY ../package*.json ./
RUN yarn install
COPY ../ .
RUN yarn build

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "http-server", "dist", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

***docker-compose.yml***

```
version: '3.5'
services:

  simple-chat:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
    image: simple-chat
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    volumes:
      - ../:/app/simple-chat
```

Comment: by using `volumes` you're not containerizing the application, as you want to run from a local folder, and compose, if only one service, you don't even need to use it, right? the `docker run` would ultimately run it...

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

You have mistaken the `http-server` path on Dockerfile

`CMD [ "http-server", "/app/simple-chat/dist"]`

Remove the `volumes:` from compose if you want containerize app (you copy everything on Dockerfile) otherwise remove the `COPY` from Dockerfile and set
`volumes:`

### Consideration

1. Is possible to build a vuecli app without vuecli but you know some consideration see this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59103389/is-it-possible-to-build-a-vue-application-without-vue-cli) post.

Comment: the OP is probably running `docker` under Windows, see e.g. [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48623005/9164010) which deals with winpty.

Comment: Also, you only said that `docker-compose` is not necessary, but the crux of the issue raised by the OP is probably the unexpected `volumes:` field, which should be removed, as pointed out by [@balexandre's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65648243/dockerize-vue-project/65656891#comment116070088_65648243)

Comment: Finally, note that even if one only has one container, `docker-compose` can still be handy to easily run the container with a single command (`docker-compose up`), avoiding a long list of CLI arguments and relying on a "declarative spec" (docker-compose.yml): see e.g. [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65570951/9164010) where I gave a pointer to a tool that can *automate* the generation of the docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: @ErikMD I updated the answer with your suggestions

Comment: OK! but it doesn't seem you actually took them into account? (regarding `docker-compose` :)